# Chrome browser quit after loading from selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, selenium-ide

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService`
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get('https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed')

all_matches_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[@analytics-event='All matches']")
all_matches_button.click()

# driver.quit()
```

- selenium version = 4.9.1
- python version = 3.11.3

I don't understand what's the problem.  If anyone understand the problem please fix this.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: can you send us the failure logs or anything to understand the issue?

Comment: Do you mean what closes after the program is executed? Try adding `time.sleep(20)` for example after `all_matches_button.click()`. Don't forget the `import time`.

Comment: time.sleep(20) delays 20 s to close the browser.

Comment: but why it automatically quit while I didn't add any driver.quit()/ driver.close() code. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That occurs because chrome automatically closes when the code has finished running.

You might wanna use the following script for testing:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService`
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get('https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed')

all_matches_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[@analytics-event='All matches']")
all_matches_button.click()

input("Press ENTER to quit")
driver.quit()
```

Note: You'll still want to execute `driver.quit` in the end, as the temporary folder in your filesystem gets flooded elsewise

Answer (score 0):

1. When ChromeDriver be killed， it will close the browser，to sove this：

```
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

[-> Official Document about 'detach' option](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities)

2. when script end，the browser sometimes also close (with Pycharm "Run")，to sove you can try：

```
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
```

## notice, this will disable log output

The browser close may due to no place to send logs after script ends.

you also Try run script in "Terminal" or Windows cmd terminal.
[image]